# Check for role in allow()-function and set warning if denied

Tags: javascript, meteor

I m using `alanning:roles` and want to check for the given role to give access to the DB. Is it possible to do some code if access is denied - something like a notice?

**Update**

As you can see, I didn't understand the throw error method at all.

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'crashme':function() {
        throw new Meteor.Error(402, "Access Denied", "details", "more details");
    }
});

Users.allow({
    insert: function(userId) {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin')) return true;
    },
    update: function(userId) {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin')) return true;
    },
    remove: function(userId) {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin')) return true;
    }
});
```

On client-side I do

**client.js**

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, 'anything');

Meteor.call("crashme", function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If the addUsersToRoles fails, the user should see a notice...

Comment: yes, this should work. Of course, this will show up on your *server* console, not your client. But it's also very easy to check on the client, since the insert or update will fail with an error in the callback.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure, if I understand you. I want to give a notice info to the user on the client side. But I don't know where to put the code. The above code is on the server-side of course...

Comment: ok, now I understand your problem. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a meteor exception on the server side - catch the exception on the client.

Give your exception a message - display it to the user.

```
throw new Meteor.Error(XX,e.message);
```

See the following:
[Throwing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151249/how-do-i-view-thrown-errors-in-meteor-methods)

Try something like this:

```
Users.allow({
    insert: function(userId) {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin')) 
           return true 
        else 
           throw new Meteor.Error(xx,xx);
    }
});
```

On the client

```
SomeCollection.remove(someId, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err.message); // Outputs "Not the owner"
});
```

Please look at this post too: [also shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571552/meteor-customizing-errors-messages-from-allow-and-deny-rules)

Comment: That sounds logic. Can you please give an example?

Comment: See the link in my post.

Comment: Read the link and the docs, but unfortunately I don't fully understand the handling. Updated my post, so you will see my problem.